# How to use msbuild inside BeforeBuild Exec?

Tags: msbuild, wix, wix3.11

I have a Wix Installer project that needs to run `msbuild` in order to generate the .dll files and the executable, I currently have it inside my project like so:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- Publish dotnet core app -->
    <Exec Command="msbuild /p:configuration=release ..\Regulator2App.WPF\Regulator2App.WPF.csproj" />
    ...
</Target>
```

When I build the Installer project I get the following error:

```
The attribute "Version" in element <PackageReference> is unrecognized.  Regulator2App.Installer C:\Users\Iván\Desktop\regulator2app\Regulator2App\Regulator2App\Regulator2App.csproj
```

Pointing to this line:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="GuerrillaNtp" Version="1.4.1" />
   ...
</ItemGroup>
```

And then the command exits with code 1.

How can I add the msbuild command to my installer? What needs to be added/changed?

I have the exact same setup as [this tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Yf-eDsRrnM)

Comment: I would take a look at this (my) tutorial: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I create an Application.sln and an Installer.sln and build the former and then the later.   I talk about it in my tutorials at https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials.

Comment: Thank you your tutorials are really useful. I ended up solving this issue by adding a reference in my PATH environment variable to my msbuid folder but in the future I will defintely read up your work.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful tutorials. Exactly what I needed. I used them to create an installer for a windows service and the process was by far the best installer creation experience I have had.